# Filter java stream by array index

Tags: java, java-stream

I am having a file with rows like this:

```
Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, female (%),United Republic of Tanzania,2015,76.08978
Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, female (%),Zimbabwe,2015,85.28513
Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, male (%),Honduras,2014,87.39595
Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, male (%),Honduras,2015,88.32135
```

If I do this:

```
try {
            Stream<String> file = Files.lines(Paths.get("file.csv"));
                file
                .filter(r -> r.startsWith("f",43))
                .forEach(r -> System.out.println(r));
                file.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I get females. 
Why this does not work?

```
        .map(row -> row.split(","))
        .filter(r[2].startsWith("f"))
```

I can print r[2] like this

```
    .forEach(r -> System.out.println(r[2]));
```

So that r[2] at least exists.

Comment: why not using ``match()`` or ``contains()``?

Answer (score 1):

You have spaces after your commas, so the split method will return strings that start with commas. Therefore, you need to use `r.split(",")[2].charAt(1) == 'f'` or `r.split[2].startsWith(" f")` to account for that space.

```
file
  .filter(r -> r.split(",").startsWith(" f")) OR .filter(r -> r.split[2].charAt(1) == 'f')
  .forEach(r -> System.out.println(r));
```

Also, as Ousmane D. pointed out, you shouldn't have `.filter(r[2].startsWith("f")`, it should be `.filter(`**r ->** `r[2].startsWith(" f")`, but that's probably just a typo

User8641 has also suggested using the regex `" *, *"` with the split method to remove all spaces before and after commas, so that you can keep using your original `startsWith("f")`

Comment: might also be worth mentioning the argument to `filter` should be a function given the OP is calling it as `.filter(r[2].startsWith("f"))`. unless it's just a typo when posting his question...

Comment: I made this change .map(row -> row.split(",")) to this .map(row -> row.split(",  ")). Still can't filter with .filter(r[0].startsWith("f")). Netbeans says: can not find symbol.

Comment: Use `.filter(r -> r[2].startsWith("f"))` if you've made that change

Comment: Use .filter(r -> r[2].startsWith("f")) worked. Thank you.

Comment: use ``split(" *, *)`` to skip any spaces

Comment: @Lasse, if this answer works for you, consider accepting it.